# Unification of python command line interpreter and command-subcommand command line interfaces

Tags: python, command-line, interface, tab-completion

I have an command line interpreter (or "line-oriented command interpreter" in the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) for the `cmd` module) for a program that I'd like to add command line utility interface to.
  For example, now a session looks like this: (`%` for shell prompt, `:)` is my custom prompt)
`% tasks` (invokes command line interpreter) 
`:) clockHours Teaching_Sara_to_coregister_T1_to_T2` 
`:) exit` 
In addition, I want this interface: 
`% tasks clockHours Teaching_Sara_to_coregister_T1_to_T2`

I envision custom interpreter commands mapped onto subcommands in the command line utility.  Does there exist a library for doing these together?  It would be great not to have to write completion code twice, command structure code twice, etc.  If not, any advice for me if I try to implement this behavior, or thoughts on how useful it might be?

Obviously I lose the advantage of simple temporary variables, which is why I was using the interpreter approach to begin with, but many of my custom interpreter commands do not rely on this behavior, or could be easily modified not to require it - it is that subset that I want command line utility subcommands for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd` module may be enough for what you want if I correctly understand your problem.

Your final solution may be close to below example:

```
import cmd
import sys

class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    def do_hello(self, line):
        print "hello"
    def do_exit(self, line):
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_cmd = MyCmd()

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        my_cmd.onecmd(' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
    else:
        my_cmd.cmdloop()
```

giving this behavior:

```
C:\_work\home>jython cmdsample.py hello
hello

C:\_work\home>jython cmdsample.py
(Cmd) hello
hello
(Cmd) exit

C:\_work\home>
```

Comment: Good lookin'- thanks.  There is the issue of autocompletion, but that's a shell thing I guess - ideally I write wrappers such that I can specify autocompletion behavior once, and it gets used in both situations, but it the autocompletion mechanisms might be too different for this to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing that you may find useful is [cmdln](http://code.google.com/p/cmdln/) module.

Comment: Hm, I'll look into it - I've used cmd2 before, but never cmdln.

Comment: I'm confused by the documentation - does this do cmd.py-like things at all (like ftp), or just command line stuff (like git, hg)?

Comment: The primary purpose of the tool is to create command line stuff like git, hg. I didn't investigate compatibility with `cmd` module to provide interactive features with the same interface, but it seems natural to have this support there.